# Set variable value in method under test in Junit

Tags: java, junit, mocking

How can we set value of some integer variable in a method under test in Junit? This is just a made up code to reproduce the problem I have. Here is the code:

```
void someMethod(long l) {
int i = 0;
while (i < l) {
    if (i == Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
        throw new RuntimeException;
    }
    i++;
}
```

I need to set i to 2,147,483,647 in test to check that when the if condition is true, it properly throws the exception.

Comment: "*How can we set value of some integer variable in a method under test in Junit?*" - We don't. We test behaviour, i.e. what the code does, given a specific input. A local variable is not part of the input, it is part of the unit under test. Why do you want to do this? Therefore, we do not - and in fact cannot  - modify it. This seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: You're right. I didn't do good job explaing my problem. Let me take some time re edit it . Thanks for the response.

Comment: Let me know when you have edited the question. As an aside: I would recommend renaming the parameter `long l` to `long g`. This minimizes the risk of someone misreading the `l` for an `i` or vice-versa.

Comment: I am voting to close the question due to inactivity and missing information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, my question was not descriptive of the problem that i had.
I was able to create an instance variable

```
int maxVal = Integer.MAX_VALUE
```

So, the method looked like this:

```
void someMethod(long l) {
    int i = 0;
    while (i < l) {
        if (i == maxVal) {
            throw new RuntimeException;
        }
        i++;
    }...
```

and then set the instance variable to a different value at the test case, 0 in case of the code above, and it threw exception like i had wanted.

Thanks Turing85 for that clue.

Answer (score -1):

You can pass argument long l to be Integer.MAX_VALUE+1 this will allow i to be equal to Integer.MAX_VALUE and you will get exception thrown.

Comment: The post is about the local variable `int i`, not the parameter `long l`.

Comment: You're right. Maybe I did not do a good job explaining my problem. 

Comment: Code under test should not be modified as per any test condition, hence i suggested using a appropriate test case input which can invoke the desired code. i could have explained it better :)